# Using variables from other Python file

Tags: python-3.x, replit

I am making a little game thing in Python, I'm still fairly new to this. I am trying to access a variable in another file by using import, but it keeps saying

> AttributeError: module 'core temp' has no attribute 'ct'

This is my code I am trying to run:

```
elif cmd == "temp":
    if core.ct < 2000:
      print(colored("Core temperature: "+core.ct+"°C", "green"))
    elif core.ct < 4000:
      print(colored("Core temperature: "+core.ct+"°C", "yellow"))
    elif core.ct >= 3000:
      print(colored("Core temperature: "+core.ct+"°C", "red"))
```

I am importing coretemp like this: `import coretemp as core`

This is the code in coretemp.py:

```
from time import sleep as wait
import coolant as c

ct = 10

while True:
    if c.coolactive == False:
        ct = ct + 1
        wait(.3)
    else:
        ct = ct - 1
        wait(1)
```

I've been stuck on this problem for ages!

PS: sorry if things aren't formatted right, I'm on mobile and it's hard.

Comment: Is that code in "coolant"?

Comment: The first block of code is in main, the second is in coretemp

Comment: What is the name of your main script? Make sure you are not attempting to import the main script anywhere as that can cause problems like this: if the script was `coolant.py` then the import in `coretemp` would import a second copy of the script which would be trying to access the `coretemp` module before it had executed. That would give the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Duncan the main file is main.py

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see you would get this error is if the `coolant` module also imports `coretemp`. (BTW, I am assuming here the space in `core temp` was a copy/paste error)

If `coolant` imports `coretemp` it will be accessing a copy of the module as it existed when `coretemp` imported `coolant`. That would mean `ct` is not yet defined.

Note that the import in `main` will never complete as `coretemp.py` contains an infinite loop at the top level: `main` will simply wait for ever for the module it is importing to finish executing.

Comment: Yeah, last night I tweaked the code a bit and realized that the while True loop would stop everything. However, I need an infinite loop to either increase or decrease ct. Is there a way to do this without pausing everything else?